# Proving that the clique cover problem is in NPC by reducing from k-coloring

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions

Provided that we have to compare it against the graph coloring problem which is NPC. So far,
I can only think of connecting edges from a vertex in a provided graph to all the other edges it is not connected to then I separate the new graph g2, then I connect all the vertices that are not connected in the g2. And then I count the number of subsets. However it doesnt seem to work with a graph that requires four colors?

Comment: It sounds like you're already on the right track. Making a vertex adjacent to the vertices it was not adjacent to (and not adjacent to those it was adjacent to) is called taking the *complement* in graph theory. It seems to be a good choice for a first step. Can you elaborate on why you think your solution does not work for four colors?

Comment: say suppose i have clique graph g2 where max clique size is 4, Since they are already all connected/complete graph , I cant do the step that I just mentioned. Also it's a clique cover problem that we have to prove is NPC. I think I don't get what a clique cover problem is?

Comment: If your original input is $K_4$, then its complement separates into 4 $K_1$s (single vertices). So you have four cliques that cover the complement and require four colors. If your original input is 4 vertices with no edges, then the complement is a clique, so you can cover the complement with one clique and only need one color.

Answer (score 2):

In the interests of putting up an explicit answer, your approach is correct. The proof is sketched on the [Wikipedia page for Clique Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem).

The reduction itself is fairly straightforward. The reasoning is that if a graph is $k$-colourable, then it can be partitioned into $k$ independent sets (one for each colour class), then we just exploit the normal reduction between Independent Set and Clique by taking the complement graph (we swap edges for non-edges and vice versa), so any independent set becomes a clique. So if $G$ is $k$-colourable, it can be partitioned into $k$ independent sets and hence $\overline{G}$ can be partitioned into (i.e. covered by) $k$ cliques (but not necessarily by $k$-cliques ;) ). Conversely if $\overline{G}$ can be covered by $k$ cliques, $G$ has a partition into $k$ independent sets, and hence is $k$-colourable.